# Trying to insert picture in external Css with id element, no answer to solution works

Tags: html, css, image

The path for the images is exactly the way it is typed out but still unable to see any results. Been at this longer than is sane and nothing has worked after countless tutorials and forum sifting.
p.s. Path read as follows C:\users\my_name\Desktop\Consoles\Html Cheatsheet\Html exercise\Images\Pain Stake barebones.

`````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css%style.css">
</head> 
<body>

    <div id="picture-css">````





    </div>


</body> 
</html></code></pre>





   ````<code><pre> 
          #picture-css
          {
          width:900px;
          height:auto;
          background-image:url(../Images/Pain Steak  barebones.png);
          } 
          </code></pre>````
`````

Comment: Enclose the url between quotes. If the url contains spaces you have to

Comment: Well thanks for the idea but it seems that i have no clue how to write this code properly. it just gets more and more clutter the further it goes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-image:url('../Images/Pain Steak  barebones.png');`

works, but to prove that try to set also:
`min-height:200px;`

as `height:auto;` is not forcing non-zero height.

I have a working example here: http://xcc.me/222/

UPDATE:

the `%` in the `href="css/css%style.css"` is a special character that will nto work on it's own, so if you cannot rename `css%style.css` in the HTML you can write it out as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css%25style.css">
```

as the urlencoded version of `%` is `%25` in UTF8, and this will work.

Example: http://xcc.me/223/

Comment: thanks for that but it's in an external CSS that the ID is written not so sure exactly what it is i am leaving out even with the spaces being replaced by underscores in both the source file and the url

Comment: I just modified my example, and I think the `%` in the `href="css/css%style.css"` is tripping you. Can you rename `css/css%style.css` to `css/css_style.css`? This works for me. See updated http://xcc.me/222/

Comment: still nothing It might be just too many files with the same name in the same folder with slight differences in numbers or phrasing. When you add the comments do you need to also add them in the example that is on my project as well.

Comment: Still the same. thanks Ron, It looks as if the code just isn't suppose to be, even when the the css is added into the html internally it stays the same in the default viewer

Comment: Well then there are some other thing at play.. from what I see (you provided) I was able to show why it is not working. If it is still not working for you, then we here are missing something that you additionally have on your end.

Comment: yeah haha, i was using a free course on udemy and I think there is a slight language barrier between the instructor and I.

Comment: i could submit a screen shot if that would be something that makes a difference

Comment: What is the encoding of your HTML file? `%25` would work only if it is UTF8

Comment: when i added an image internally in the html file it displayed so the path isn't what's the problem, also it was a different file like a jpeg that was inserted this time. and the src element was used.

Comment: Seems you are now changing the original question.. If you add an image inline, you are not using LOADING the external CSS file, thus it will all work.. as from what I gathered the issue was that the external CSS was not loading, and I explained why :)

Comment: yeah it's giving me a right time figuring out what I am omitting in my exercise, I even renamed all the files putting ''css/css%style.css'' as "css/style(2).css"and reworked it so it was close to the example you provided. would you suggest that the css i am using is confused with the prior css i entered for another exercise in the same folder ? thanks for your time ha it's probably annoying have to waste it on a simple fix.

Comment: #page-title{
text-align:center;

}


#picture-container 
{
width: 400px;
/*height: 400px;*/
margin: 0 auto;
 

border: 2px solid azure;
padding: 20px;
background: maroon;





img#image
{
  border: 2px solid aliceblue;
   border-radius: 5px;
}


#picture-css
{
 width:900px;
 height:300px;
 background-image: url('.../Img/meerkat_lounging_1.jpg')
 ;
}